# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Bank::sacar(), 0 passed in

Tags: php, html

it is throwing this error and I cannot figuire out what is going on.
I'm trying to simulate a bank where you can deposit and withdraw.
When I comment the "depoistar, sacar, pagarMensal and fecharConta" the error desapears I have no clue I've trying look into some forums but I've got no lucky.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <pre>
        <?php
            require_once 'bank.php';
            
            //Jubileu
            $p1 = new Bank();
            $p1->abrirConta("CC");
            $p1->setDono("Jubileu");
            $p1->setNumConta(1111);
            print_r($p1);
            $p1->depositar(300);
            $p1->sacar();
            $p1->pagarMensal();
            $p1->fecharConta();

            //Creuza
            $p2 = new Bank();
            $p2->abrirConta("CP");
            $p2->setDono("Creuza");
            $p2->setNumConta(2222);
            print_r($p2);
            $p2->depositar(500);
            $p2->sacar(100);
            $p2->pagarMensal();
            $p2->fecharConta();
        ?>
    </pre>
    
</body>
</html>
```

bank.php

```
<?php

class Bank{

    /**
     * ATRIBUTOS
     */
    public $numConta;
    protected $tipo;
    private $dono;
    private $saldo;
    private $status;

    /**
     * METODO CONSTRUCTOR
     */
    public function __constructor(){
        $this->saldo = setSaldo(0);
        $this->status = setStatus(false);
    }

    /**
     * METODOS
     */
    public function abrirConta($t){
        $this->setTipo($t);
        $this->setStatus(true);
        if($t == "CC"){
            $this->setSaldo(50);
        }
        else if($t == "CP"){
            $this->setSaldo(150);
        }
    }
    public function fecharConta(){
        if ($this->getSaldo() > 0) {
            echo "<p>Conta ainta tem dinheiro, não podes fechá-la!</p>";
        }
        else if($this->getSaldo() < 0){
            echo "<p>Conta está em débito. Impossível encerrar!</p>";
        }
        else{
            $this->setStatus(false); 
            echo "<p> Conta de ". $this->getDono() ." fechada com sucesso.</p>";
        }

    }
    public function depositar($v){
        if ($this->getStatus()) {
            $this->setSaldo($this->getSaldo() + $v);
            echo "<p> Depósito de R$ $v na conta de " . $this->getDono() . " </p>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<p> Conta fechada. Não podes sacar.</p>";
        }
    }
    public function sacar($v){
        if ($this->getStatus()) {
            if ($this->getSaldo() > $v) {
                $this->setSaldo($this->getSaldo() - $v);
                echo "<p> Saque de R$ $v autorizado na conta de" . $this->getDono() . "</p>";
            }
            else{
                echo "<p> Saldo insuficiente para saque.</p>";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "<p> Não podes sacar duma conta fechada.</p>";
        }
    }
    public function pagarMensal(){
        if ($this->getTipo() == "CC") {
            $v = 12;
        }
        else if ($this->getTipo() == "CP") {
            $v = 20;
        }
        if ($this->setStatus()) {
            $this->setSaldo($this->getSaldo() - $v);
            echo "<p> Mensalidade de R$ $v debitada na conta de". $this->getDono() ." </p>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<p> Problemas com a conta. Não poder ser cobrada.</p>";
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * GETTERS & SETTERS
     */
    // CONTA
    public function getNumConta(){
        return $this->numConta;
    }
    public function setNumConta($nc){
        $this->numConta = $nc;
    }

    //TIPO
    public function getTipo(){
        return $this->tipo;
    }
    public function setTipo($t){
        $this->tipo = $t;
    }

    //DONO
    public function getDono(){
        return $this->dono;
    }
    public function setDono($d){
        $this->dono = $d;
    }

    //SALDO
    public function getSaldo(){
        return $this->saldo;
    }
    public function setSaldo($s){
        $this->saldo = $s;
    }

    //STATUS
    public function getStatus(){
        return $this->status;
    }
    public function setStatus($st){
        $this->status = $st;
    }
}
```

Comment: `sacar($v)` must have a value eg `sacar('45')`

Comment: Please be more specific about the errors you're getting, and what do you try to achieve. Telling us the errors disappear when you comment your code doesn't help us to help you.

Comment: I was having troblue making the following ones to work propery.
$p2->depositar(500); //deposit | $p2->sacar(100); //withdraw | $p2->pagarMensal(); //pay monthly tax | $p2->fecharConta(); //close account
I was having troubles trying to make these methods work propery, but I figure out what
the problems were.in the file bank.php there was a method pagarMensal() I was calling the method setStatus() which should be getStatus(), well this on problem. The other problem was the other I was using the print_r(); so I wasn't seen the updated numbers after fixing that my code worked.I'll post the code

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.
I was having troblue making the following "I don't know how call them if methods or object or maybe another name" ones to work propery.

> $p2->depositar(500); //deposit
>
> $p2->sacar(100);     //withdraw
>
> $p2->pagarMensal();  //pay monthly tax
>
> $p2->fecharConta();  //closeaccount

I was having troubles trying to make these methods work propery, but I figure out what the problems were in the file bank.php there was a method pagarMensal() I was calling the method setStatus() which should be getStatus(), well this on problem. The other problem was the other I was using the print_r(); so I wasn't seen the updated numbers after fixing that my code worked.

index.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>
            <?php
                require_once 'bank.php';
                
                //Jubileu
                $p1 = new Bank();
                $p2 = new Bank();
                $p1->abrirConta("CC");
                $p2->abrirConta("CP");
                $p1->setDono("Jubileu");
                $p2->setDono("Creuza");
                $p1->setNumConta(1111);
                $p2->setNumConta(2222);
               
                $p1->depositar(300);
                $p2->depositar(500);
                $p1->sacar(338);
                $p2->sacar(30);
                $p1->pagarMensal();
                $p2->pagarMensal();
                $p1->fecharConta();
                $p2->fecharConta();
    
                print_r($p1);
                print_r($p2);
            ?>
        </pre>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Bank.php

```
<?php
    class Bank{
        /**
         * ATRIBUTOS
         */
        public $numConta;
        protected $tipo;
        private $dono;
        private $saldo;
        private $status;
    
        /**
         * METODO CONSTRUCTOR
         */
        public function __constructor(){
            $this->saldo = setSaldo(0);
            $this->status = setStatus(false);
        }
    
        /**
         * METODOS
         */
        public function abrirConta($t){
            $this->setTipo($t);
            $this->setStatus(true);
            if($t == "CC"){
                $this->setSaldo(50);
            }
            else if($t == "CP"){
                $this->setSaldo(150);
            }
        }
        public function fecharConta(){
            if ($this->getSaldo() > 0) {
                echo "<p>Conta ainda tem dinheiro, não podes fechá-la!</p>";
            }
            else if($this->getSaldo() < 0){
                echo "<p>Conta está em débito. Impossível encerrar!</p>";
            }
            else{
                $this->setStatus(false); 
                echo "<p> Conta de ". $this->getDono() ." fechada com sucesso.</p>";
            }
    
        }
        public function depositar($v){
            if ($this->getStatus()) {
                $this->setSaldo($this->getSaldo() + $v);
                echo "<p> Depósito de R$ $v na conta de " . $this->getDono() . " </p>";
            }
            else{
                echo "<p> Conta fechada. Não podes sacar.</p>";
            }
        }
        public function sacar($v){
            if ($this->getStatus()) {
                if ($this->getSaldo() > $v) {
                    $this->setSaldo($this->getSaldo() - $v);
                    echo "<p> Saque de R$ $v autorizado na conta de" . $this->getDono() . "</p>";
                }
                else{
                    echo "<p> Saldo insuficiente para saque.</p>";
                }
            }
            else{
                echo "<p> Não podes sacar duma conta fechada.</p>";
            }
        }
        public function pagarMensal(){
            if ($this->getTipo() == "CC") {
                $v = 12;
            }
            else if ($this->getTipo() == "CP") {
                $v = 20;
            }
            if ($this->getStatus()) {
                $this->setSaldo($this->getSaldo() - $v);
                echo "<p> Mensalidade de R$ $v debitada na conta de ". $this->getDono() ." </p>";
            }
            else{
                echo "<p> Problemas com a conta. Não poder ser cobrada.</p>";
            }
        }
        
        /**
         * GETTERS & SETTERS
         */
        // CONTA
        public function getNumConta(){
            return $this->numConta;
        }
        public function setNumConta($nc){
            $this->numConta = $nc;
        }
    
        //TIPO
        public function getTipo(){
            return $this->tipo;
        }
        public function setTipo($t){
            $this->tipo = $t;
        }
    
        //DONO
        public function getDono(){
            return $this->dono;
        }
        public function setDono($d){
            $this->dono = $d;
        }
    
        //SALDO
        public function getSaldo(){
            return $this->saldo;
        }
        public function setSaldo($s){
            $this->saldo = $s;
        }
    
        //STATUS
        public function getStatus(){
            return $this->status;
        }
        public function setStatus($st){
            $this->status = $st;
        }}
```